# How do I use Windows 7 calculator in programmer mode?

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to use the Windows calculator in programming mode but there are very poor instructions on what the keys are for.  First off, does anyone know where to find instructions on using this mode? 
 I want to be able to convert numbers between Decimal to Binary or Binary to Decimal. At least 32 bits if possible.  I'm having problems just trying to enter more that two digits before it bleeps at me.  i.e.: 15 will work but 115 bleeps at me.

I'm not sure if this calculator mode can be used for signed integers or not.
Does anyone know how to enter signed numbers like (-1234) and (+3645)

Answer (score 5):

> I want to be able to convert numbers between Decimal to Binary or Binary to Decimal. At least 32 bits if possible. I'm having problems just trying to enter more that two digits before it bleeps at me. i.e.: 15 will work but 115 bleeps at me.

Assuming you've selected `Programmer` <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> from `View` in the calculator window, now:

1. Select the radio button before `Dec`
2. Now enter the value (decimal)
3. Now select the radio button before `Bin`
4. The converted binary is displayed.
5. Clear the contents using the button `C` or `CE` and type the binary data and repeat `step 1` to see its decimal form.

`Dword` is 32 bit long, `Qword` is 64 bit long.

To get negative value, press `-` button or <kbd>-</kbd> before entering the value and use <kbd>=</kbd>. That way you can handle negative values.

From [how-to-convert-twos-complement-calculator-program-and-usage-example](https://superuser.com/questions/109150/how-to-convert-twos-complement-calculator-program-and-usage-example?rq=1)

> Additionally, negative numbers are shown in two's complement (and the sign change key performs two's complement on the displayed value). Src: [Planetmath](https://planetmath.org/WindowsCalculator)

Comment: Thank, How do I use the bitwise keys? (and, or ,not, etc..)

Comment: Visit the shortcut key mapping at https://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-8 ... Please note that bitwise operations are applicable in binary mode. (I'll edit the answer ASAP when I reach my PC)